# Can an app register itself to consume certain URLs?

Tags: default-applications, intents

This is *not* a programming question but a usability one.

News site example.com has an annoying habit: when I follow a link to an article, the site first displays a pop-up saying “come use our app instead!” So I did, but article links still open the web browser, and still bring up that pop-up.

I’d like to file a bug with the app developer. Could the app have been designed to consume all URLs beginning with `http://example.com/`? (Otherwise I’ll complain to the web site designers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is generally referred to in Android parlance as an "intent filter", and yes - Android supports this via the [`<data>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) in the application's manifest file. You could point them to that documentation link in your bug report. You can also find examples on Stack Overflow with some relevant code samples:

- [Android Respond To URL in Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent)
- [Intercepting links from the browser to open my Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app)